# Put comma after every nth characters , but it should not be inside a word

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a long string, I have to put comma after every 300 characters.

I am using this and it is working fine:

```
select regexp_replace(column_name,'(.{300})','\1,') from table_name ;
```

But the condition is we cannot put any comma inside a word. So we have to check if the 300th character is a space, then put a comma, else find the previous space and put comma there.

A similar scenario: (I am taking 10 instead of 300)

After running the query

```
select regexp_replace(column_name,'(.{10})','\1,') from table_name ;
```

Sample Input: (i.e. value of column_name):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras viverra consectetur magna, vel vulputate sapien convallis ut.
```

Sample Output:

```
Lorem ipsu,m dolor si,t amet, co,nsectetur ,adipiscing, elit. Cra,s viverra ,consectetu,r magna, ,vel ,vulputate sapien ,convallis ,ut.
```

But this is unexpected.

The output should be like this:

```
Lorem ,ipsum dolor ,sit amet, ,consectetur ,adipiscing, elit. ,Cras viverra ,,consectetur magna,, vel ,vulputate sapien ,convallis ,ut.
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: If this is a one-time activity, i would just write a plsql for loop to iterate over the string and find the correct place to insert the comma

Comment: I have to achieve this in Oracle using  SQL . I cannot use PL/SQL or any code

Comment: Your expected output makes no sense. As per your description, there should **not** be comma between `v,el`  and `Cra,s` . Also, why do you want 2 commas after `amet` ?

Comment: Sorry , the description was wrong , I corrected it

Comment: Actually I will divide the string into lines using connect by . 1st I'll replace the existing commas in the string by something else , then put the comma using the logic , then divide it and then replace the something else with commas

Comment: Still there are few  like `vulputa,te`

Comment: I didn't understand your comment, you mean you want to use something like this as a solution or are you describing the steps you are going to perform after this operation?

Comment: Keep my comments apart . I want something as I described .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used `|` rather than a comma since the sample data you've provided uses commas:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/67f20/18)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name( data ) AS
SELECT 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras viverra consectetur magna, vel vulputate sapien convallis ut.' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH words ( id, data, word, wordno, numwords, len, grpstart, grp ) AS (
  SELECT ROWNUM,
         data, 
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( data, '^\S+', 1, 1 ),
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT( data, '(^|\s)\S+' ),
         LENGTH( REGEXP_SUBSTR( data, '^\S+', 1, 1 ) ),
         0,
         0
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         data, 
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( data, '\s\S+', 1, wordno + 1 ),
         wordno + 1,
         numwords,
         len + LENGTH( REGEXP_SUBSTR( data, '\s\S+', 1, wordno + 1 ) ),
         CASE
         WHEN len + LENGTH( REGEXP_SUBSTR( data, '\s\S+', 1, wordno + 1 ) )
              > grpstart + 10
         THEN len
         ELSE grpstart
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN len + LENGTH( REGEXP_SUBSTR( data, '\s\S+', 1, wordno + 1 ) )
              > grpstart + 10
         THEN grp+1
         ELSE grp
         END
  FROM   words
  WHERE  wordno < numwords
)
SELECT LISTAGG( words, '|' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY grp )
         AS sentence
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         grp,
         LISTAGG( word, '' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY len ) AS words
  FROM   words
  GROUP BY id, grp
)
GROUP BY id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/67f20/18/0)**:

```
|                                                                                                                            SENTENCE |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Lorem| dolor sit| amet,| consectetur| adipiscing| elit.| Cras| viverra| consectetur| magna,| vel| vulputate| sapien| convallis| ut. |
```

Comment: Appreciate your dedication to write this... I was lethargic to even start, looking at the requirement. :-}

Comment: Thank you very much . It is working absolutely fine , but the column on top of which we are making these is a CLOB column and also the no of charecters is 300. So the query is taking long time to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding something like [^a-z] in your regular expression to exclude all characters from a-z.